# how can i structure a multi-threaded code for better code reuse in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, code-reuse, code-structure

I am building a multi-threaded project in Java, I have entities and DAO packages to wrap the database tables and manipulating them. I have processing package which contains Runnables. The way i have implemented the Runnables so far is like this:

```
Class Thread1 implements Runnable{
  Thread t;
   parameters
  ...

  public Thread1(){
    t = new Thread(this,"Thread1");
    ....
    t.start();
  }

  public int method1(){
  ...
  return x;
  }

  public double method2(){
  ...
  return y;
  }

  public void run(){
    // some processing using DAO methods
    ....
    method1();
    ... 
    method2();
    ...
  }

}
```

The code works this way, but i need to use the same processing in the `run()` method as part of the processing in `Thread2` class. The way i have structured my code does not allow to reuse the code. what would be a better structure to resolve this?

Comment: Side comment: why do you call a Runnable `Thread1`? Why not `Runnable1`?

Comment: @assylias I am creating a thread inside that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

1. Make `Thread1` and `Thread2` extend the same abstract base class, and move shared logic to the parent (inheritance).
2. Create a common interface that both classes implement and that contains the common methods, then create a separate class that implements `Runnable`, and implement `run()` there (composition).

You should always favour composition over inheritance, so the second option is usually better, because it also gives you the flexibility of changing behaviour at runtime.

For example:
Create a shared interface first

```
public interface SharedTask {
    public void method1();
    public void method2();
}
```

Make both classes implement it:
`public class Thread1 implements SharedTask` and `public class Thread2 implements SharedTask`.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    public Worker (SharedTask task) {
        this.task = task;
        ...
    }

    public void run() {
        task.method1();
        task.method2();
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in your code:
`new Worker().start();`

Comment: I did not get the second option.. so both classes would not be Runnables? and they will create an instance of the the separate Runnable class? If that's the case, what will go into the `run` method?

Comment: got it, but this way the common methods will be implemented twice in both classes (the implementation is the same for these common methods). Is there anyway to avoid implementing them in a superclass as you suggested to avoid inheritance.

Comment: For shared functionality, it would be better to make `SharedTask` as an Abstract class and implement them there and use a hybrid solution of both methods. There is no general rule of thumb that says extension is bad, you just have to be careful not to overuse it, as it makes your code less re-usable.

Answer (score 1):

You almost never want to create and launch the Threads yourself.  Just implement Runnable (or, if you prefer, Callable).  Then submit them to an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which provides all sorts of cool options for how many threads it is running (and an nice central location to change this in the future should your needs change), tie-ins to a CompletionService, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class that implements `Runnable` with the code you want in its run method - then extend that class as many times as you need the same functionality in your run method.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into the nifty details of multithreading: chances are that all your DAO calls will be run on one database connection, thus (almost) on one db thread. (especially if use some ORM framework, but a simple datasource pool will give you the same effect) You can definitely get rid of this issue, but it means that you have to use XA resources with two-phase commit to stay ACID compliant. That **is** a big chunk of work, so unless you're ready to do that, it's pointless to think about the appserver-side multithreading nuances.